# Rectangle fitting in SMT syntax (Z3 solver)

Tags: boolean, z3, smt, sat

I try to place N rectangular blocsks with different sizes into a grid, by formulating it
as a CSP propblem.
The blocks should not overlap with each other, they can touch on the edges, and there can be
empty places.
For example place 4 rectangular blocks of size 2x2 into a 8x8 grid. (Vary the number of blocks, the sizes of the blocks, and the size of the grid.) I know the formula as
[image]

I try to write a program or script generates the formula but I am confused too much I cant write in an SMT syntax. İf anyone helps I aprreciate too much. Thank you.

Comment: To solve your (homework?) problem: Choose your decision variables; define type and value range per variable; define the constraints; translate your model into [SMT2](https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2021-05-12.pdf) syntax; run Z3. If you get stuck on your way, post a specific question.

Comment: You might benefit from the [MinizInc model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66918091/1911064) I posted for a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66899645/finding-all-the-combinations-n-rectangles-inside-the-square/66918091#66918091).

Answer (score 1):

You should be specific about what you tried and what didn't work. If your problem is with syntax, then here's something to get you started:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)

(declare-fun xi () Int)
(declare-fun wi () Int)
(declare-fun xj () Int)
(declare-fun wj () Int)

(assert (or (<= (+ xi wi) xj)
            (<= (+ xj wj) xi)))
```

The above encodes the first two disjuncts in your formula. You can add the other variables and assert all the other conditions as required.